# Access denied finding property "vendor.debug.egl.swapinterval" I am keep getting this error in android studio when I run my app

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I am getting this errors lots in lots. Here is the fraction of it.

```
10-17 18:21:33.518 6476-6503/royal.com.ocr E/libc: Access denied finding property "vendor.debug.egl.swapinterval"
10-17 18:21:41.614 6476-6503/royal.com.ocr E/libc: Access denied finding property "vendor.debug.prerotation.disable"
10-17 18:21:41.615 6476-6503/royal.com.ocr E/libc: Access denied finding property "vendor.debug.prerotation.disable"
10-17 18:21:41.615 6476-6503/royal.com.ocr E/libc: Access denied finding property "vendor.debug.prerotation.disable"
10-17 18:21:41.623 6476-6503/royal.com.ocr E/libc: Access denied finding property "vendor.debug.egl.changepixelformat"
10-17 18:21:41.656 6476-6503/royal.com.ocr E/libc: Access denied finding property "vendor.debug.egl.swapinterval"
10-17 18:21:41.682 6476-6503/royal.com.ocr E/libc: Access denied finding property "vendor.debug.egl.swapinterval"
10-17 18:21:42.965 6476-6503/royal.com.ocr E/libc: Access denied finding property "vendor.debug.egl.swapinterval"
10-17 18:21:42.972 6476-6503/royal.com.ocr E/libc: Access denied finding property "vendor.debug.egl.swapinterval"
10-17 18:21:42.993 6476-6503/royal.com.ocr E/libc: Access denied finding property "vendor.debug.egl.swapinterval"
10-17 18:21:43.010 6476-6503/royal.com.ocr E/libc: Access denied finding property "vendor.debug.egl.swapinterval"
10-17 18:21:43.023 6476-6503/royal.com.ocr E/libc: Access denied finding property "vendor.debug.egl.swapinterval"
10-17 18:21:43.036 6476-6503/royal.com.ocr E/libc: Access denied finding property "vendor.debug.egl.swapinterval"
10-17 18:21:43.054 6476-6503/royal.com.ocr E/libc: Access denied finding property "vendor.debug.egl.swapinterval"
```

Comment: You may have to follow [this](https://github.com/aagarwal1012/Image-Steganography-Library-Android/issues/1)

Comment: I saw this stream of access errors on my OnePlus6T device in Android Studio as well.
My device was running OxygenOS version 9.  Upgrading Oxygen to v10.3.8 eliminated the errors.

Comment: @SanthoshJoseph In general, how would one go about diagnosing this type of "access denied" error in libc for properties related to google android devices?  This is currently the first google search result that comes up for [ libc property access denied ] type searches, at least for me.  Answering the general form of the original question could be useful here.

Answer (score 38):

You might be using Android Pie+, probably OnePlus6 or above.

There are few workarounds.

1. Highlight part of the line in your logcat that you don't want to
   see, right click, then go for `Fold lines like this`.
2. Exclude that tag (together with "RenderThread") in Android Studio
   logcat filter config using this regex: `^(?!(libc|RenderThread))`

Answer (score 4):

Add this line in your manifest file.

```
<uses-library android:name="org.apache.http.legacy" android:required="false"/>
```

Comment: Thank you! It fixed a crash with Google Maps API on Android 9.0

Comment: Omitting Apache HTTP libraries has nothing to do with the error messages from the OP. The Logcat messages are related to OpenGL commands.

Comment: @theapache64 Nope, it is still happening and I haven't found any solution yet.

Comment: @Óscar Did you try [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53916264/4370279) solution ?

Comment: @theapache64 No, I haven't, but I guess this is only a filter, isn't it?

Comment: @Óscar. Yes. As this is a device specific issue, fixing it at device level feels like a load. So I think filtering is the best solution for now.

Answer (score 4):

This is due to some rendering bug comes with API 28. Check your **build.gradle** file in the project folder($PROJECT_FOLDER/android/app/). If **compileSdkVersion** and **targetSdkVersion** is set to **28** . Please change it to **27** .I

Comment: faced this issue, inside Flutter project when using oneplus 6 under developer mode, issue resolved.

Comment: Bundles built with targetSdkVersion 27 are now rejected by Play Store

Answer (score 2):

> E/libc: Access denied finding property "vendor.debug.egl.swapinterval"

this is the **Access denied finding property** type error.

which is probably caused by previous related **warning** like this:

`type=1400 audit(xxx): avc: denied { xxx } for name=xxx dev=xxx ino=xxx scontext=xxx tcontext=xxx tclass=xxx permissive=0`

## how to fix `avc: denied` error ?

- Simple:

  - refer offical doc [Validating SELinux  |  Android Open Source Project](https://source.android.com/security/selinux/validate) try use `audit2allow` and related tool to fix.
- Detailed:

  - refer my [another post's anwser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59533551/access-denied-finding-property-persist-vendor-log-tel-dbg/63259127#63259127)

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
flutter run --enable-software-rendering
```

Working for me!