# what does the following means in flutter

Tags: flutter

I am getting like this in terminal whenever I run my application.

```
W/1.gpu   (27112): type=1400 audit(0.0:4901991): avc: denied { read } for name="u:object_r:vendor_default_prop:s0" dev="tmpfs" ino=16976 scontext=u:r:untrusted_app:s0:c232,c256,c512,c768 tcontext=u:object_r:vendor_default_prop:s0 tclass=file permissive=0
E/libc    (27112): Access denied finding property "vendor.debug.egl.swapinterval"
I/flutter (27112): controller changed
I/flutter (27112): focusnode changed
I/flutter (27112): format changed
I/flutter (27112): controller changed
I/flutter (27112): focusnode changed
I/flutter (27112): format changed
E/libc    (27112): Access denied finding property "vendor.debug.egl.swapinterval"
```

is there anything wrong since I am new to flutter I dont have the clear idea of the flow in flutter apps.

Comment: Maybe related https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52855807/access-denied-finding-property-vendor-debug-egl-swapinterval-i-am-keep-getting

Answer (score 0):

it's not related to your code and you can just ignore it.

unfortunately, there is no way I know of to hide these logs for now in android studio.