# Access denied finding property "vendor.oplus.media.vpp.stutter"

Tags: android, flutter, admob, admob-rewardedvideoad

Thankyou in advance for reading this question. Im currently trying to use google admob in my apps, it is working, but i kept getting spam of  Access denied finding property "vendor.oplus.media.vpp.stutter".

This is the package that im using https://pub.dev/packages/google_mobile_ads/example

I put the admob code in my second page. It wont come up if i havent access that page. but as soon as i open the ads it wont dissapear even when im not in that second page anymore.

Im using the Google Rewarded ad btw if that helps.

[image: My Debug Console]

i already tried to comment any print statement in my code but it still wont dissapear. seems like it generated automaticly. Already tried to google it but cant find the exact same one.

Comment: unfortunately no, it's still spamming in my debug console. @Varun

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The logs seems to indicate that the device you're running on is a One Plus. If `google_mobile_ads` plugin works without issues, then this warning can be safely ignored. However, if you'd like to hide the logs, here's a [workaround](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53916264/2497859) that you can follow.

Comment: Okay thankyou sir, it's indeed running without a problem. just bit worried of it kept spamming the log